# Use Google maps in Android application

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it legal for me to use Google Maps in my application for commercial purpose? Or do I need to purchase an API key? If yes, please tell me how. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Thanks mate I think it's free.

Comment: yes free see my ans below and feel free to ask if any doubts

Answer (score 1):

You need an API key to sign your app.

You can do this [here](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html).  Regarding whether it is legal or not to use it for commercial purpose, read the terms and conditions at the bottom of this link.  If it doesn't say you can't, then you should be all set.

On a side note, you don't pay for anything.  Register, and it's free!

Comment: Thanks mate I think it's free.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation says the following:](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

> Because MapView gives you access to Google Maps data, you need to register with the Google Maps service and **agree to the applicable Terms of Service** before your MapView will be able to obtain data from Google Maps. This will apply whether you are developing your application on the emulator or preparing your application for deployment to mobile devices.

So the answer to your question is: Yes, you will need an API key.

Getting an API key is free - even for a commercial application - [and can be done here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html).

Comment: Thanks mate I think it's free.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm fairly sure the T&C used to say you couldn't charge for your app if it use Google Maps. Now I see that it says "You can charge a fee for your Maps API Implementation if it is an Android application downloadable to mobile devices from the Android Market." I wonder when it changed?

Answer (score 0):

You need api key in your app.

you need to generate MD5 fingerprint then place this MD5 fingerprint  in this [link](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-api-signup.html) you will get the api key.

To generate MD5 fingerprint 
follow this link it will be useful http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android(study this link)

that api key should be placed in mapview

eg:android:apiKey="0l4sCTTyRmXTNo7k8DREHvEaLar2UmHGwnhZVHQ"